# Cannot login to wp-admin as redirect set to page not yet published

Tags: login

I know exactly what is happening but not how to fix it.
I set up a login redirect to a page that I only have as pending/draft. 
I think I need to either cancel this redirect or somehow publish the missing page.
Any help gratefully received, thanks

Comment: How did you set that redirect? If via plugin/theme, renaming the folder should deactivate it, allowing you to login again

Comment: If you know what happen why not revert and verified that this was the problem? This seems a very general question as without more info cannot tell what is the best approach.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. It was a plugin so I deleted the folder via ftp and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

Typically if you lock yourself out on WordPress side the easiest approach is to edit/delete code responsible.

Often this is just FTP or something and whacking it. In more elaborate setups you might not have access and get the person with such to take care of it.